# Event for dismissing onscreen keyboard by clicking the keyboard button

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, cocoa-touch

I've been looking everywhere... maybe i'm not using the right searchwords since i do believe this is a common question.

Is there an event i can handle for when the user dismisses the keyboard by clicking the button to lower the keyboard.

[image: The red marked button]

i move a view up when a uitextfield becomes firstresponder but i want to move it down again when this button is tapped

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using notifications. Add that to your `viewDidLoad`:

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(keyboardWillHide:) name:UIKeyboardWillHideNotification object:nil];
```

and then create a method called `keyboardWillHide`:

```
- (void)keyboardWillHide:(NSNotification *)notification {
  //do whatever you need
}
```

Hope it helps

Comment: for swift 4, it is UIResponder.keyboardWillHideNotification

Answer (score 0):

Check out the second paragraph in the "Managing Keyboard" section: http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/DOCUMENTATION/UIKit/Reference/UITextField_Class/Reference/UITextField.html

Answer (score 0):

By using NSNotificationCenter you get Keyboard events.You can register for keyboard events in viewWillAppear and don't forget to unregister in viewWillDisapper.
We will use here two notifications :

1. UIKeyboardDidShowNotification [apple docs](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#DOCUMENTATION/UIKit/Reference/UIWindow_Class/UIWindowClassReference/UIWindowClassReference.html)
2. UIKeyboardDidHideNotification [apple docs](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#DOCUMENTATION/UIKit/Reference/UIWindow_Class/UIWindowClassReference/UIWindowClassReference.html)

   You can do some thing like this:

   - (void) viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated {
     [super viewWillAppear:animated];
     NSLog(@"Registering for keyboard events");

   // Register for the events
   [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter]
    addObserver:self
    selector:@selector (keyboardDidShow:)
    name: UIKeyboardDidShowNotification
    object:nil];
   [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter]
    addObserver:self
    selector:@selector (keyboardDidHide:)
    name: UIKeyboardDidHideNotification
    object:nil];

   // Setup content size
   scrollview.contentSize = CGSizeMake(SCROLLVIEW_CONTENT_WIDTH,
                                       SCROLLVIEW_CONTENT_HEIGHT);//for e.g. (320,460)

   //Initially the keyboard is hidden
   keyboardVisible = NO;//in .h declare BOOL keyboardVisible;
   }

-(void) viewWillDisappear:(BOOL)animated {
    NSLog (@"Unregister for keyboard events");
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter]
     removeObserver:self];
}

**-(void) keyboardDidShow: (NSNotification *)notif** {
    NSLog(@"Keyboard is visible");
    // If keyboard is visible, return
    if (keyboardVisible) {
        NSLog(@"Keyboard is already visible. Ignore notification.");
        return;
    }

```
// Get the size of the keyboard.
NSDictionary* info = [notif userInfo];
NSValue* aValue = [info objectForKey:UIKeyboardBoundsUserInfoKey];
CGSize keyboardSize = [aValue CGRectValue].size;

// Save the current location so we can restore
// when keyboard is dismissed
offset = scrollview.contentOffset; //in .h declare CGPoint offset and UIScrollView *scrollview.;

// Resize the scroll view to make room for the keyboard
CGRect viewFrame = scrollview.frame;
viewFrame.size.height -= keyboardSize.height;
scrollview.frame = viewFrame;

CGRect textFieldRect = [activeField frame];//in .h UITextField *activeField;
textFieldRect.origin.y += 10;
[scrollview scrollRectToVisible:textFieldRect animated:YES];    

// Keyboard is now visible
keyboardVisible = YES;
```

}

**-(void) keyboardDidHide: (NSNotification *)notif** {
    // Is the keyboard already shown
    if (!keyboardVisible) {
        NSLog(@"Keyboard is already hidden. Ignore notification.");
        return;
    }

```
// Reset the frame scroll view to its original value  
scrollview.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, SCROLLVIEW_CONTENT_WIDTH, SCROLLVIEW_CONTENT_HEIGHT);  

// Reset the scrollview to previous location
scrollview.contentOffset = offset;

// Keyboard is no longer visible
keyboardVisible = NO;
```

}

-(BOOL)textFieldShouldReturn:(UITextField *)textField
{
    [textField resignFirstResponder];
    return YES;
}
hope would help you :)